# Conditional independence and independence when CDF is given

Tags: probability, independence

I have a problem in my probability exercises and I have the following question regarding it,

I am given two random variables, $X_1$ and $X_2$.

$X_1$ has a CDF of $F_{X_1}(x,\theta)$ and $X_2$ has a CDF of $F_{X_2}(x,\theta)$.

It is given that $T_1|\theta$ is independent from $T_2|\theta$.

**Edit: It is given that $\color{red}{X_1}|\theta$ is independent from $\color{red}{X_2}|\theta$**

Does this mean that $T_1$ is independent of $T_2$ ?

**Edit: Does this mean that $\color{red}{X_1}$ is independent of $\color{red}{X_2}$ ?**

Can I write, say,
$$ Pr(X_1 >x_1, X_2 > x_2) = \bigg(1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_{X_1}(x_1,\theta)F_{\theta}(\theta) d\theta\bigg) \times  \bigg(1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_{X_2}(x_2,\theta)F_{\theta}(\theta) d\theta\bigg)$$

Is this correct? The distribution of $\theta$ is given as Gamma, if that helps. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear how $T_1, T_2$ relate to $X_1, X_2$.  But if $T_1, T_2$ are conditionally independent given $\theta$, that does not mean they are independent. Consider the counter-example $\theta, U_1, U_2$ iid uniform $[-1,1]$ and let $T_1=\theta + U_1$, $T_2=\theta + U_2$.

Comment: @Michael sorry, corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using $T_1, T_2$ is a typo, I think you mean $X_1$ and $X_2$ are conditionally independent given $\theta$. This does not mean $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent (see counter-example in my comment above). So your proposed equation is incorrect.

Fortunately, a correct equation can be obtained just as simply. If you are given $X_1, X_2$ are conditionally independent given $\theta$, you should directly use that information to compute $P[X_1>x_1, X_2>x_2]$ by conditioning on $\theta$ (via the law of total probability).  You know how to condition on all possible values of $\theta$ to compute the probability of an event involving one random variable.  You can use the same technique to condition on an event involving two random variables. Note that in general, if $A$ is an event, then the law of total probability says:

$$ P[A] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|\theta=u] f_{\theta}(u)du$$

Can you give an answer now?  Possibly typing up your own answer to the question here, or giving it in a comment?

Comment: PS: I observe that your attempt to compute the marginal uses $F_{\theta}$ instead of $f_{\theta}$.  This problem does not require you to compute marginals, but FYI a correct expression would be $$ P[\underbrace{X_1\leq x_1}_{A}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underbrace{P[X_1 \leq x_1|\theta = u]}_{P[A|\theta =u]}f_{\theta}(u)du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_{X_1|\theta}(x_1 | \theta=u)f_{\theta}(u)du$$

Comment: @MichaelThank you! So I'm after $Pr[X_1> x1, X_2 > x2].$ I could write it as: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Pr[X_1>x_1, X_2>x_2|\theta=u]f_{\theta}(u) du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Pr[X_1 >x_1 | \theta = u] Pr [X_2>x_2|\theta=u]f_{\theta}(u) du$$ which equals to: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1- F_{X_1|\theta}(x_1|\theta=u)(1- F_{X_2|\theta}(x_2|\theta=u)f_{\theta}(u)du$$

Comment: Yes that is correct.